# looking up for loaded modules/services in jxta

Tags: java, service, p2p, jxta

When we load a service using loadModule into a custom peergroup, what is the way that we can look up for that service under that group for later usage.
I tried lookupService method of the peergroup but it simply says "service not found" even though the module has been loaded and started perfectly and im using the correct ModuleClassID for looking up
i tried the deprecated methods here, using stdparamadv.. apparently they dont work properly with builds 2.6 and 2.7 of jxta

Answer (score 0):

The service feature of JXTA is unfortunately poorly designed and ought to be re-written from scratch. As I mentioned in other posts on the net, people should avoid using JXTA to load services. Use OSGi instead (for example).

The service feature of JXTA has not been fully tested (mostly because of a lack of resources and interest from the community). We focused on other key issues first. It is possible that loading services on customized peergroups may contain a bug indeed.